# Where should I keep my business layer in MEAN Stack development?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean

I am developing an web application using MEAN stack but instead of Mongo I am using MySQL. I am quite confuse where should I keep my business logic. I saw suggestions of keeping it with angular. Is it secure to keep it in anugular? or should I keep it in backend?

Comment: of course in backend

Comment: Business logic belongs to the backend. But to really make a statement, you should provide more information